# RandomForestClassifier with n_estimators=1 and min_impurity_decrease=0 yields 100% train accuracy on complex dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a RandomForestClassifier in sklearn with the following parameters:

```py
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1,
                             min_impurity_decrease=0,
                             max_features=3,
                             bootstrap=False,
                             random_state=j,
                             criterion='entropy',
                             warm_start=False)
```

Features and Labels:

- My feature matrix X (pd.DataFrame) has shape (100,110), i.e. 110 features.
- The labels are vectors of length 10, i.e. I am trying to predict 10 targets.

The feature matrix contains a feature x_i for i=1,...,10 from which I construct the labels:

```py
y_i = np.sign(X['x_i'].diff(1).shift(-1))
```

The labels are in {-1,1} (no label value 0 possible) and they are the one-step-ahead change of the feature x_i for i=1,...,10. The label vector at each time t is then given as the set of all labels at time t:

```
y[t] = {y_i[t] | i=1,...,10}
```

While training the classifier, I noticed that the training accuracy is 100% for `min_impurity_decrease=0`, and the test accuracy is between 50-60%. This happens even in the extreme case of `n_estimators=1`, which is just a single tree.

When I increase `min_impurity_decrease>0`, the training accuracy decreases, while the test accuracy remains roughly the same.

It seems to me that there is some kind of leakage going on during the training, because of which the classifier achieves such high training accuracy and overfits.

Strangely, even if I entirely remove the features x_i from the feature matrix, and just use them to construct the labels, the high training accuracy persists. Finally, even if I only predict the label for a single target x_i, i.e. y_i, the training accuracy is still 100%. Also I checked my dataset several times, it should be ok. I am out of explanations.

Why this high accuracy is achieved even with a single tree? It seems highly illogical to me.

Comment: I guess training on only 100 samples is an issue

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: thanks, ill try with more samples. and concerning closing of the question; i did not just ask for theoretical aspects, also for the correctness of the way that i coded the computation of the labels. but feel free to close it, if you insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the max_depth argument to something other than the None, which is default. It expands the tree until you rich 100% accuracy, that's the reason. It obviously overfits. Use max_depth=2, 4, 8, etc.